# $\mathrm{Var}X\quad X|N=n\in(-1)^{N}\quad N\in \text{Ge}(p)$

Tags: probability

Let $N\in \text{Ge}(p)$ and set $X=(-1)^{N}$. Compute $\mathrm{E}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X)$.

$\mathrm{E}(X)=p\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k}(-1)^{k}=\frac{p}{2-p}$

$\mathrm{E}(X^{2})=p\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{2k}(-1)^{k}=p\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-(1-p)^{2})^{k}=\frac{p}{1+(1-p)^{2}}$

$\mathrm{Var}(X)=\frac{p}{1+(1-p)^{2}}-(\frac{p}{2-p})^{2}=\frac{p(4-6p+3p^{2}-p^{3})}{(2-p)^{2}(1+(1-p)^{2})}$

From the book $\textit{(An intemediate course in probability, Allan Gut)}$ I got that $\mathrm{Var}(X)=\frac{4(1-p)}{(2-p)^2}$.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key error is this: in your expression for $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$, you squared the probability term rather than the value term. To follow along your method, you should have written
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\mathbb{E}[(-1)^{2N}]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(-1)^n]^2P(N=n).
$$
Notice here that $[(-1)^n]^2=1$ for all $n$, so that really this is
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(N=n)=1,
$$
because we are summing over all possibble outcomes for $N$.

But, notice something interesting here:  $X^2=[(-1)^N]^2=1$ for any integer value of $N$.  So in fact, we could have gotten $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=1$ directly.

Now, you can write
$$
\text{Var}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2=1-\frac{p^2}{(2-p)^2}=\frac{(2-p^2)-p^2}{(2-p)^2}=\frac{4(1-p)}{(2-p)^2},
$$
as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake happened when calculating $E(X^2)$. You squared the wrong term in the sum.

Comment: It seems so, yes. My error. Thank you!